# Copying a zip from /assets to sdcard

Tags: android, osmdroid

I have a .zip file in my assets folder, which I want to copy 1-1 to a .zip in a folder on my device.

It kind of works, but the output zip contains also stuff that I do not understand.

What I have:

Input:

> assets:
>    Map.mp3

Output:

> Map.zip
>
> > assets+META-INF+org+res+AndroidManifest.xml+classes.dex+resources.arsc (all APK file)

Whereas in Map.zip/assets there is a Map.mp3 with the initial content. But I just need to have a 1-1 copy with just file extension changed.

My code:

```
//taken from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4447477/android-how-to-copy-files-from-assets-folder-to-sdcard
        AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
        AssetFileDescriptor assetFileDescriptor = null;

        try
        {
            assetFileDescriptor = assetManager.openFd("Map.mp3");
            // Create new file to copy into.
            File output= new File(_FILEPATH_ + java.io.File.separator + "Map.zip");
            output.createNewFile();
            copyFdToFile(assetFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor(), output);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


public static void copyFdToFile(FileDescriptor src, File dst) throws IOException {
    FileChannel inChannel = new FileInputStream(src).getChannel();
    FileChannel outChannel = new FileOutputStream(dst).getChannel();
    try {
        inChannel.transferTo(0, inChannel.size(), outChannel);
    } finally {
        if (inChannel != null)
            inChannel.close();
        if (outChannel != null)
            outChannel.close();
    }
}
```

`_FILEPATH_`=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/osmdroid"

Answer (score 0):

You can always use simple file copy procedure:

```
private void copyFile(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int read;
    while((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1){
      out.write(buffer, 0, read);
    }
}
```

Method with usage of `FileDescriptor` is not working with compressed files.
As I understand, you get such solution from [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11212942/1219012).
The comment below,

> My solution was to change the extension to .mp3, then remove it once
>   copied

that suggest to rename extension to .mp3 is dated by Dec 19 '12 at 2:07. Google may change `FileDescriptor` usage and close that thrick with renaming.

I'm using simple procedure in my Android project and all works fine, there is no performance issues.